# Access specific element in list in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I've got a list of thumbnail urls stored as a list in a MongoDB document.

I can access all of these urls by looping through them:

```
{{#each thumbs}}
   <img src="{{.}}">
{{/each}}
```

However, I would like to just get the first thumbnail (so without looping through all of them). I've tried `{{thumbs[0]}}`, but this doesn't work

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: @IanClark Googled it, went through the docs, nothing showed up.

Comment: Have you tried `thumbs.[0]`?

Comment: You have to create helper for {{thumbs}} that looks thumbs: function(){ return thumbs[0]};

Comment: @Ben no problem. Answer version supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `thumbs.[0]`, which I found within the Spacebars' **[README](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md)**:

> A Spacebars path is a series of one or more identifiers separated by either . or /, such as foo, foo.bar, this.name, ../title, or **foo.[0]**.